# jQuery POST in ASP.NET MVC 3 app failing to onvoke callback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have this jQuery POST call which worked fine in my MVC 3 app running in IIS 5.1
I upgraded to win 7 w/ IIS 7.5 and I get this error alert:
Error=jQuery15104282204828902775_1304784218121 was not called & Status=parsererror

```
function Post() {
    var ow = "musa";
    var cmt = $("#comment").val();
    var app = "pa";
    var id = "76575abcd3665cdfe32987";
    $.ajax(
     {
         type: "POST",
         url: "/comment/Save",             
         dataType: "json",
         data: "app=" + app + "&id=" + id + "&au=" + ow + "&cmt=" + cmt,
         success: function (result) {
             alert("Success");
             if (result.status === "OK") {
                 alert('Author:' + result.au + " App:" + result.app + " id:" + result.id);
             }
             else
                 alert("Status was not a success");
         },
         fail: function ShowFail(xhr) {
             alert("Sorry! Failed");
         },
         error: function (req, status, error) {
             alert('Error=' + error + ' & Status=' + status);
         }
     });
}
```

But in HttpFox it shows Status is 200 OK

This is my controller:

```
public class CommentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(string app, string id, string au, string cmt)
    {
       //return these to callback
       return Json(new { status = "OK", app=app, id=id, au = au, cmt=cmt});
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: try this: `dataType: 'text json',` instead of `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Wow! That rocks. Now why do I need text json instead of just json?

Comment: May be I am not passing a json formatted data..but it works in iis5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/` the built in converters support the following conversions (and the functions they call):

1. `* text` - `window.String`
2. `text html` - `true` (no clue what this is)
3. `text json` - `jQuery.parseJSON`
4. `text xml` - `jQuery.parseXML`

Each converter's value is a function that returns the transformed value of the response.

Comment: It seems jQuery 1.5 has issues with $.ajax(). I migrated to jquery 1.6 and now datatype: "json" works fine as before

Comment: be careful because 1.6 had several breaking changes.